# How to use foreach in an async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am working on a .net Maui android application. I have a method with a foreach loop. First I get the items from the database, then I have to add them to an observablecollection. Because the list could consist many items, I have noticed that it could take some time before it's complete. During the process it blocks/freezes up the UI. I am wondering what would be a good way to add the items in parallel without freezing up the app.

Consider the following code:

```
private IDataService _dataService;
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

public MainPageViewModel(IDataService dataService)
{

  Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
  _dataService = dataService;

}

Public async Task LoadItemsFromDbAsync()
{
   List<Item> ItemList = await _dataService.GetItemsAsync();
   Foreach(Item item in ItemList)
   {
     Items.Add(item)
   }        
}
```

The mainpage.xaml.cs

```
private MainPageViewModel _viewModel;

public MainPage(MainPageViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = viewModel;
    BindingContext = _viewModel;
}

protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
   await _viewModel.LoadItemsFromDbAsync();
}
```

I have tried to following:

**Option 1**
This didn't work. It gave the following error:

`Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException:** 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }


Public async Task LoadItemsFromDbAsync()
{
   List<Item> ItemList = await _dataService.GetItemsAsync();
   var tasks = new List<Task>();
   foreach (Item item in Itemlist)
   {
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => AddItemToCollection(item)));
   }
  
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

}

private void AddItemToCollection(Item item)
{
   Items.Add(item)
}
```

**Option 2:**

This option works, but it seems to do exactly the same as the original and still blocking the UI until complete.

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

Public async Task LoadItemsFromDbAsync()
{
   List<Item> ItemList = await _dataService.GetItemsAsync();
   var tasks = ItemList.Select(async item =>
   {
     Items.Add(item);

   });

   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Please include how you call LoadItemsFromDbAsync.

Comment: Depending on the amount of items you are flooding the UI with notifications (ObservableCollection) and that will slow down the UI. I personally would create a new ObservableCollection and assign that to the Items property. One notification and all Items are rendered in one go.

Comment: @SirRufo I tried your option and I figured out that indeed it is not the foreach loop that is blocking the UI. It seems like it is the rendering of the updated ObservableCollection if it contains many items.

Comment: The exception is valid even for User Interface controls built on Windows Forms projects. Its an InvalidOperationException that makes sure the original thread that created a control can update it. You can work around this by using variables then use new threads to update the variable and then use the original thread to update the control with the value updated by the second thread.

Comment: Do you present your data in a grid? If so you should consider using paging. With .Skip(x).Take(y) on the DB you can fetch the page you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

The `ObservableCollection` is not thread-safe, so you have to choose between following options:

1. Don't use `Items` in different threads.
2. Use thread-safe collections from [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent) namespace.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering what would be a good way to add the items in parallel without freezing up the app.

You're already using asynchronous code to retrieve the data for the items, so your performance problem is actually adding the items to the list.

And that's a problem.

First, this means you're probably adding tens of thousands of items to a list that you expect to display to a user and have the UI be usable. This just doesn't work.

What you actually need to do is design a UI that isn't as overwhelming for the user. I.e., consider some form of paging or [load-on-scroll system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#load-data-incrementally) instead of loading everything into the UI all at once.

If you really do want to show the user thousands and thousands of items, then you'll need to use data virtualization, because no UI framework is designed to actually show that much data.